# No DisplayMember in CheckedListBox in WinForms .Net 3.5

Tags: winforms, checkedlistbox

What should I use instead? I've tried DataBindings.Add , but my data were not loaded
I have data structure with 3 properties: ID, Name and e.g. Description. I want to load the whole data to the list, but to show only Name property. Usually I use DisplayMember for this purpose, but I here I couldn't find it.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I solved the problem according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9dzztb.aspx
simply adding my objects to the list and changing ToString method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called `DisplayMember`. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.displaymember.aspx) link.

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about DisplayMember, usually such controls have it, but in my case I have only DataBindigns and DisplayRectangle

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.displaymember.aspx

Answer (score 6):

DisplayMember and ValueMember are marked as non-browsable, so they are not visible using Intellisense. Here's CheckedListBox class metadata:

```
// Summary:
//     Gets or sets a string that specifies a property of the objects contained
//     in the list box whose contents you want to display.
//
// Returns:
//     A string that specifies the name of a property of the objects contained in
//     the list box. The default is an empty string ("").
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[Browsable(false)]
public string DisplayMember { get; set; }
```

Anyway, they can actually be used, just use them as properties with the right casing and you shouldn't receive any design-time error.

Answer (score 1):

Also from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9dzztb.aspx)

> Note: 
>   You cannot bind data to a CheckedListBox. Use a ComboBox or a ListBox for this instead. For more information, see How to: Bind a Windows Forms ComboBox or ListBox Control to Data.